# Apache commons fileupload FileItemIterator hasNext() always returns false

Tags: java

In my *web.xml*, there are no filters.
In my HTML, name attribute in input field is already mentioned.
I'm not using any *getParameter()* or *getAttribute()* APIs before parsing the HTTPRequest.

After all this, I'm still unable to get any elements.
Please explain why?

My MVC controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/upload"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void uploadFileHandler(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
{
    // Check that we have a file upload request
    boolean isMultipart = true;//ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
    if(true == isMultipart)
    {
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
        while (true == iter.hasNext()) 
        {
            FileItemStream item = iter.next();
            String name = item.getFieldName();
            InputStream stream = ((ServletRequest) item).getInputStream();
            if (true == item.isFormField()) 
            {
                System.out.println("Form field " + name + " with value " + Streams.asString(stream) + " detected.");
            } 
            else 
            {
                String fileName = item.getName();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My html file:

```
var fileSelector = document.createElement('form');
fileSelector.setAttribute('id', 'uploadForm');
fileSelector.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
fileSelector.setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');

var inputType = document.createElement('input');
inputType.setAttribute('type', 'file');
inputType.setAttribute('name', 'uploadedFile');
inputType.setAttribute('id','importFile');
fileSelector.appendChild(inputType);
```

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
           url:  'upload',
           data: formData,
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           cache: false,
           type: 'POST',
           success: function(data)
           {
                alert("upload success");                
           },
           error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert("upload fail");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is some conflicts in configuration. You're basically mixing two different file upload API's. The second one will get only an empty stream.If you use commons-fileupload streaming api, you may need to add spring.http.multipart.enabled=false in you application.properties if you use Spring boot.If you want to upload file by using MultipartFile, you need to enable multipart.

Answer (score 1):

It is required to set following in application properties file

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=false
```